# Collective term for all those involved in producing a film?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that covers both the cast and crew of a film? I'm certain there is but can't think of it and, given the topic, Googling just results in lists of films.

Can someone please tell me what it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theatre there's *company*, but the way of doing business has long since been different, and that affects the terminology. First there was the "stable" approach where actors were under contract to studios, and now we have hiring done on a per-film basis for both minor and major actors (though the negotiations involved are very different for obvious reasons). This difference in how they are hired makes for a difference in their business relationship to the film, as well as the obvious difference in how they are more visible.

So we have *cast* and *crew* as separate concepts, and "cast and crew" used regularly when there is a need to refer to both. So regularly in fact that it's become an idiom; it would be understood standing on its own to probably refer to a film or television production, and is found much more often than the logically equivalent "crew and cast" as this ngram query shows:
[image]
So, even if there were a term that covered both, you'd be more immediately understood using "cast and crew", and should probably favour it anyway.

It's worth noting that "cast and crew" generally includes those involved in serious decisions about films (such as the directors, writers and producers), though *crew* on its own often excludes these (who are referred to separately as *film-makers*).

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to believe, but maybe, just maybe, there is no such world in wide use.

What I did find is to use the two individual words together, like *cast & crew*

Examples of this include [Winter in the Blood homepage](http://winterinthebloodfilm.com/cast-crew/), a [BBC documentary](http://www.bbc.co.uk/filmnetwork/filmmaking/guide/production/cast-and-crew) about making films and a *Cast and Crew* listings for films on IMDB.